# How to Customize Top navigation or the Action bar in MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm having no luck to find solution online, is there any way to change the action bar properties or customize it.
I want to add an action in the action bar like a setting or a logout,(Flyout menu, shell content title, another action)

I tried everything online but they all lead to adding another item in the flyout menu.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Shell.TitleView` to custom the Top navigation. Such as:

In the AppShell.xaml:

```
 <Shell.TitleView>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="9*,1*">
            <Label x:Name="title" HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button Text="Log Out" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>
    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="NewPage"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage1}"
        Route="NewPage" />
```

And in the code behind:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
      
      public AppShell()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // logout here
    }
    protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigated(args);
        title.Text = Shell.Current.CurrentItem.Title;
        // make the title always show correctly
    }
}
```